# Не могу запустить скрипт по примеру из книги How to Tango with Django

Tags: python, django

Добрый вечер! Имеется скрипт из книги

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',
                    'tango_with_django_project.settings')

import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',
                    'tango_with_django_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()
from rango.models import Category, Page

def populate():
    python_pages = [
    {'title': 'Official Python Tutorial',
     'url':'http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial'},
    {'title':"How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
     'url':"http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/"},
    {"title":"Learn Python in 10 Minutes",
    "url":"http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/"}
    ]

    django_pages = [
         {"title":"Official Django Tutorial",
         "url":"https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/"},
         {"title":"Django Rocks",
         "url":"http://www.djangorocks.com/"},
         {"title":"How to Tango with Django",
         "url":"http://www.tangowithdjango.com/"}
         ]

     other_pages = [
         {"title":"Bottle",
         "url":"http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/"},
         {"title":"Flask",
         "url":"http://flask.pocoo.org"} ]

      cats = {"Python": {"pages": python_pages},
         "Django": {"pages": django_pages},
         "Other Frameworks": {"pages": other_pages} }

    for cat, cat_data in cats.items():
        c = add_cat(cat)
        for p in cat_data['pages']:
            add_page(c, p['title'], p['url'])

    for c in Category.objects.all():
        for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
            print('- {0} - {1}'.format(str(c), str(p)))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title)   [0]
    p.url=url
    p.views=views
    p.save()
    return p

def add_cat(name):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    c.save()
    return c

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print('Starting Rango population script...')
        populate()
```

При запуске он должен выдавать примерно такой результат:

```
$ python populate_rango.py
Starting Rango population script...
- Python - Official Python Tutorial
- Python - How to Think like a Computer Scientist
- Python - Learn Python in 10 Minutes
- Django - Official Django Tutorial
- Django - Django Rocks
- Django - How to Tango with Django
- Other Frameworks - Bottle
- Other Frameworks - Flask
```

Но, увы, ничего не происходит. Уже час ломаю голову над этим. Просто при запуске пустая строчка без каких-либо ошибок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Весь последний блок начиная со строки `if __name__ == '__main__':` нужно сместить на один отступ влево. Иначе в скрипте просто нечему будет начать выполняться.

Comment: спасибо! Помогло решить проблему